# ubuntu 18.10 issue finger print issue

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, ubuntu-gnome, 18.10, fingerprint-reader

I am using ubuntu 18.10 and my laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad E480.
I want to use the fingerprint scanner given in my laptop for login.

But ubuntu setting/user does not show this option
[image]

I also tried downloading Fingerprint-GUI but it is also not working
[image]

Please help to make my fingerprint scanner work.

Comment: After installing Fingerprint GUI have you restarted the session?

Comment: I restarted my whole system

Answer (score 2):

The type of fingerprint reader in the E480 isn't supported outside of windows at the moment.
It doesn't appear to be a standard device on the PCI or USB busses.